# Not able to get form element's value after submitting form using this.form.submit();

Tags: javascript, php

Here's my HTML with PHP:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="seltemplate" id="seltemplate" style="width:150px" onChange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="0">Select a Template</option>
        <?php
        // Running the sql query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `stripo_email_templates`";
        $rs = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        // If at least one record found
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0)
        {
            // Fetch table rows
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {
                $template_id = $row['template_id'];
                $template_name = $row['template_name'];
                echo "<option value='$template_id'>$template_name</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

I am submitting form using `this.form.submit();` without any submit button.

So as soon as select list option is changed, the form is submitted.

After submission of form, I want to receive value of select list selected option.

I am echoing

```
echo $_POST['seltemplate'];
```

but no value is received. Why?

Comment: Is `$template_id` set, do the `<option>`s have values?

Comment: oops! that's the issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.form.submit()` is not good practice to write in select box element because **"this"** means select box not form or document for that you try this code.

```
function select_box_change()
{
    var f = document.getElementById('form1');
    f.action = "your_php_file";
    f.submit();
}
```

html

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
    <select id="seltemplate" style="width:150px" onChange="select_box_change();">
        <option value="0">Select a Template</option>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I am submitting form to the same page where it appears, so what will be the value of f.action?

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER['php_self']; ?> but your page can contain php script

Comment: _“`this.form.submit()` is not good practice to write in select box element because "this" means select box not form”_ - that’s why this is not `this.submit()` to begin with, but explicitly refers to the form first, by using `this.form` … There is _nothing_ wrong with that, saying it was not “good practice” is simply completely unfounded and wrong.